# Rails autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to implement autocomplete and autofill on a form. To simplify i need a function that will help me fetch existing data onto a different form. like i have record of students i need to fetch the data of students on a form via autocomplete. and the information related to that particular student should be auto filled on the form. and while doing this i do not want to leave the page.
Is there any simplified way to do this in Rails 3. any suggestions would be helpful

thanks,
nikhil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: i have gone through the auto complete app. but my requirement is not just auto complete but the record that auto complete shows, it should be automatically filled on the form. like i searched for a student in a record and i select an 'xyz' student, the data of 'xyz' student should be automatically filled on the form.

Answer (score 4):

There are no secret for doing this, go for Ajax.

Combining the `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` gem, and an simple ajax request and a little bit of jQuery, you can reach this with no big problems.

EDIT:

Here's a simple example for how you could do an ajax request on your application.

This will trigger an request when the user whatever changes the content on the "student_name" id element.

So you just have to pass the student id as an argument to this.

The student id you can obtain through the gem cited above (rails3-jquery-autocomplete)

Once you have the `responseData` in your hands you can display the data on the form fields.

```
    $('#student_name').live('change',function() {
        id = $(this).next().val;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/students/' + id,
      type: 'get',
      context: this,
      dataType: 'script',
      success: function(responseData) {
        alert('success: ' + responseData);  
      }
    }); 
});
```

Hope this help you somehow!

Comment: thanx kleber. will try out but could you redirect me to how to use ajax and jquery for the above. i don't have much of experience on ajax and jquery.

Comment: thanx very much i will try this out and will let know whether it worked or not. many thanx again

Comment: hi, i was not able to get through with the above functionality. i am not exactly getting how to implement above function.

Comment: Looks like `.live()` has been deprecated.  They're saying use `.on()` instead.